# A measure that fades over the orbits

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $\phi:X\times\mathbb{R}\mapsto X$ a continuous flow where $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space.

I am interested in this question: There is some borel probability measure $\mu$ invariant for $\phi$ such that fades along the flow orbits?, that is, 
$$\mu(\{ \phi(x,t):t\in \mathbb{R}\})=0\quad \forall x\in X.$$

I was seeing that in the discrete case it is verified with any non-atomic and invariant measure. I just started in the analysis of continuous systems and thought that such observation of the discrete case would be natural in the continuous case, but I find it difficult to find examples. So, in the flows case are there examples not necessarily lebesgue? (Since all examples I can think of are lebesgue)

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is this true? If $\mu$ is the Haar measure on $X=S^1$ and $\phi(e^{2\pi s},t)=e^{2\pi(s+t)} $. Then $\mu$ is clearly $\phi$-invariant and non-atomic, but doesn't fade along the flow orbit. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Excuse my assertion is incorrect, I assumed that the orbit has an accounting number of elements as in the discrete case, now I will edit it.

Comment: Lebesgue with any smooth flow on a manifold of dimension at least $2$ will work. Perhaps you are looking after something else?

Comment: @JohnB : Yes, one that is not lebesgue.

Comment: Lots of them, obviously, just change the density. Again: Perhaps you are looking after something else? Meaning that you should tells us why you want this.

Comment: I just edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Any measure that is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure will share this property if Lebesgue measure has it, so maybe it would help to know your goal (which the question still doesn't clarify).

Comment: @Ian Good suggestion!

Comment: @Ravi Could you explain why it does not vanishing in the orbits said measure?

Comment: Because $\mu(\{\phi(x,t):t\in \mathbb R\})=\mu(S^1) $. So this has full measure for any choice of $x$.